# R shiny table with a transpose switch

Tags: r, shiny, transpose, reshape2

I have a [Shiny server](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/server/) running with a bunch of tabs each containing a table. The content of these tables changes dynamically according to the users selection on the [`sidebarPanel`](http://www.inside-r.org/node/168812). I am using [`gvisTable`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/googleVis/docs/gvisTable) but I don't mind changing the library if needed.

The dynamic selection can make the number of columns and rows in a given table change significantly, and sometimes there is many columns and only a few rows, so it would be easier to visualise the transposed data frame rather than the original data frame.

How can I add a switch to my page so that it conditionally shows the selected data frame as originally formed or as a transposed version?

E.g. Original table and transposed table:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Id       | Column1  | Column2  | Column3  | Column4  | Column5  | Column6  | Column7  | Column8  | Column9  |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1        |  4       |  5       |   6      |   8      |   2      |   2      |     4    |    44    |   5      |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2        |  6       |  7       |   7      |   7      |   44     |   4      |    55    |     5    |   2      |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+

+----------+----------+----------+
| Id       |  1       |  2       |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Column1  |  4       |  6       |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Column2  |  5       |  7       |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Column3  |  6       |  7       |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Column4  |  8       |  7       |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Column5  |  2       |  44      |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Column6  |  2       |  4       |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Column7  |  4       |  55      |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Column8  |  44      |  5       |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Column9  |  5       |  2       |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing a dataframe to gvisTable? If so why not just pass in t(your_dataframe) ?